# Using Core Motion with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

I'm trying to move a SKSpiteNode only on the x-axis using the device motion. Tilting the device to the left or right to move the sprite. I'm reading about CoreMotion but I have doubts on how to implement this in my game.Is CoreMotion the right tool for this? And which functions to use ?
Thank you any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CoreMotion framework. Here is how you can listen core motion updates.

1- Instantiate `CMMotionManager` instance. This class is responsible to deliver motion events.

```
lazy var motionManager: CMMotionManager = {
    let motion = CMMotionManager()
    motion.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/10.0 // means update every 1 / 10 second
    return motion
}()
```

2- Call `startAccelerometerUpdates` method of motion manager. This will start your motion manager.

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
```

3- In the `update` method of your `SKScene` subclass you can read accelerometer values from motion manager. Here is how i used it.

```
let xForce = self.motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x
self.playerNodeBody.velocity = CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: 0)
```